# screen keyboard , or virtual keyboard component

Tags: c#, keyboard, touchscreen

i am making a keyboard c# control.

it has to detect the installed and active keyboard and reproduce it on screen.

i would like to iterate all keys in the currently attached(configured) keyboard, but all solutions i found on this site and on the internet use fixed layouts or a range of fixed layouts

i would like to know which keys-keycodes are available on the current locale keyboard.
could you address me to some point ?

thank you

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661722/extracting-keyboard-layouts-from-windows

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this one http://fpscomponents.com/Products/WPF/virtual-keyboard.aspx it is supplied with Layout creator, where you can create any key for any language that is installed on PC. So you can create custom keys with your picture or just text i.e. "WWW."