# Enumerating the available keyboard layouts in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

Is it possible to enumerate all the currently available keyboard layouts. By available I mean  the user can switch to them by pressing Alt+Shift (or whatever his chosen shortcut is), i.e. they are in the Language Bar's menu.

Alternatively, checking if a specific layout is available in the Language Bar would also be useful.

---

**Edit:**

Many thanks to @oleg, I finally made a function that works:

```
bool IsActiveKeyboardLayout(DWORD dwPrimaryLangID)
{
    TCHAR buf[KL_NAMELENGTH];
    GetKeyboardLayoutName(buf);

    DWORD dwActiveLangID = 0;
    _stscanf(buf, _T("%X"), &dwActiveLangID);
    if (dwPrimaryLangID == PRIMARYLANGID(dwActiveLangID))
        return true;

    return false;
}

bool IsKeyboardLayoutPresent(DWORD dwPrimaryLangID) 
{
    if (IsActiveKeyboardLayout(dwPrimaryLangID))
        return true;

    DWORD dwThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId();
    HKL hOld = GetKeyboardLayout(dwThreadID);
    for (;;)
    {
        ActivateKeyboardLayout((HKL) HKL_NEXT, 0);
        if (hOld == GetKeyboardLayout(dwThreadID))
            return false;

        if (IsActiveKeyboardLayout(dwPrimaryLangID))
        {
            ActivateKeyboardLayout(hOld, 0);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar to Extracting keyboard layouts from windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661722/extracting-keyboard-layouts-from-windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [GetKeyboardLayoutList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646297%28VS.85%29.aspx) seems get most close information to what you need. The returned information is the array of `HKL`, the HANDLE has values like

0x04070407 - German
0x04110411 - Japanese
0x04190419 - Russian
0xe0200411 - Japanese

If you have for some language more as one input methods or more as one layout for one language you can have more items as you can see in the language bar menu. On 64-bit operation system the value 0x04070407 will be represented as 0x0000000004070407.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646267%28VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_Languages_Locales_and_Keyboard_Layouts) you can read more about the input locale identifier and keyboard layouts.